# display data of child tables in the same line with a parent table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have these database structure:

```
Table1---
       ID 
       Description

Table2--
      ID
      Table1_ID
      Description
```

I dont know the number of data records in Table2. Example, I have data records of table 1 and 2:

```
ID - description
1    'des1'
```

And table 2:

```
ID - Table1_ID - description
1    1           'des2'
2    1           'des3'
```

I would like to query it somehow to view them like this:

```
Table1ID    Table1_description    table2_ID_2  table2_2_desc table2_ID_3 table2_2_desc
1           'des1'                1            'des2'        2           'des3'
```

All of the data records of table 2 will be in one line with its parent.

Would it be doable to query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only had to do this once before, and it was a bear.  I believe there are two ways, using a PIVOT, or creating some dynamic SQL.  Check out this forum for some information from people far brighter than I am: `http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/07dd8fb0-4c2c-4ed0-a6a6-4ca6a488f2d0/`